# Eclipse + MinGW: After installing another version of MinGW make still uses reference to old path

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, makefile, mingw

I'm trying to build a CPP project with make in Eclipse. I had installed some version of MinGW in `C:\MinGW\`. Consequently my system `Path` variable contained `C:\MinGW\bin` and `MinGW_Home` had that as value. 
Now I have decided to install another version of MinGW in `C:\TD_MinGW\`. I have updated my system `Path` variable to contain only `C:\TD_MinGW\bin\` (and no more the previous directory) and updated `MinGW_Home` respectively. 
I am aware of the `Environment` and `Variables` sections in the Eclipse project properties: The `Variables` are empty and in `Environment` the amendments to `Path` do not add the old path. 
Nevertheless, if I try to build any of the make targets that contain compilation, it will fail with the message `/bin/sh: c:/mingw/bin/mingw32-g++: No such file or directory`. 
 
Please, can someone give me a hint on where to remove the old reference?